# Create my own code for turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I need to know how to program my own code for turtlebot . I need to know the structure of the code and variables used when creating the program. Or if using a library that library used for programming the encoder , Kinnect , engines ...
I've been looking for and have not found anything that can serve me , could someone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198099/create-my-own-code-for-turtlebot/) by [Ruben](https://answers.ros.org/users/20796/ruben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like the basic [ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) are best suited for you.

After them. Go and work on the [Turtlebot tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also you can check the [turtlebot repository](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/tree/indigo) .

You can for example find all packages that are being used when you run the [turtlebot minimal bringup](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/blob/indigo/turtlebot_bringup/launch/minimal.launch)

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1